# Setting up email with Sendgrid in Heroku for a Django App

Tags: django, email, heroku, sendgrid

I am deploying a Django app on Heroku, and using the Sendgrid addon to send out validation email when a user registers on the site.

I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/django-example-using-smtp/) and pasted the following into `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sendgrid_username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'sendgrid_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

However, my app is crashing after registration.

What exactly am I supposed to put for `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`?

Under the developer's tab in the sendgrid addon in heroku, it gives me the username `app*******@heroku.com`, and for password it just says "Your Password". Is the password my Heroku password?

Also, do I need to include `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` in my `settings.py` file? And where do I tell Sendgrid what it is?

EDIT: I've set `DEBUG = True`, and it looks like the error is:

```
SMTPSenderRefused

(550, 'Cannot receive from specified address <info@myapp.com>: Unauthenticated senders not allowed', 'info@myapp.com')
```

it looks like the problem is happening before Sendgrid does its thing. Do I need to authenticate the email address with Heroku somehow?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Within your settings.py include:

```
import os
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['SENDGRID_USERNAME']
EMAIL_HOST= 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']
```

Edit: changed EMAIL_PASSWORD to EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD as that's the correct spelling.

Comment: I've made the changes, but still getting the error. I set debug = true, and the error is SMTPSenderRefused, saying it cannot receive from specified address <info@myapp.com>: Unauthenticated sender not allowed. Where would one authenticate email in Heroku?

Comment: Ok, actually this is the answer, but it should be "EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD" and not "EMAIL_PASSWORD"

Answer (score 0):

In the intervening 10 years, the above answer has become obsolete.  Sendgrid now uses an API key.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/django

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' # this is exactly the value 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = SENDGRID_API_KEY
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```