# How to send with Sendgrid a reset password email from a Django app deployed in Heroku?

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, sendgrid

I have been struggling for a while in trying to correctly setup the `settings.py` to send an email for password reset.This is my current configuration:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.environ["SENDGRID_API_KEY"]
SENDGRID_PASSWORD= os.environ["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]
SENDGRID_USERNAME= os.environ["SENDGRID_USERNAME"]

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['SENDGRID_USERNAME']
#EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ["DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL"]

#SENDGRID_SANDBOX_MODE_IN_DEBUG = False
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

I have come across the following posts that are related to my problem but none of them have worked:

1. [Sending SMTP email with Django and Sendgrid on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982067/sending-smtp-email-with-django-and-sendgrid-on-heroku)
2. [No module named 'sendgrid_backend' in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014049/no-module-named-sendgrid-backend-in-django)
3. [Send email with Sendgrid in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316675/send-email-with-sendgrid-in-django)
4. [Setting up email with Sendgrid in Heroku for a Django App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723494/setting-up-email-with-sendgrid-in-heroku-for-a-django-app)
5. [Heroku, Django, and Sendgrid - emails not sending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790603/heroku-django-and-sendgrid-emails-not-sending)

When I used the `EMAIL_BACKEND = "sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend"`(after I installed the `django-sendgrid-v5` library) I didn't receive any error but I didn't receive any email :'( and in the previous cases I encountered the following error `SMTPServerDisconnected at /password-reset/` and `Connection unexpectedly closed`. Any help, suggestion, comment, crazy idea is really appreciated because I have spent several hours in this problem that will be a milestone in my project.

Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue deploying a Django app on Google Cloud App Engine. The following configuration (in settings.py) worked for me:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY') 

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' # Exactly that. 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = SENDGRID_API_KEY
EMAIL_PORT = 587 # 25 or 587 (for unencrypted/TLS connections).
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.getenv('DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL')
```

For `SENDGRID_API_KEY`, use the API key created in the 'Email API/Integration Guide' section. In your case, choose the SMTP Relay option.

For `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`, use the verified single sender email. You can find it in 'Settings/Sender Authentication'. This is what you type in "from email address" when you create a Sender. More details [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/sender-verification/).

I don't recommend Robert D's answer because by using `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` you will be prone to HTTP Host header attacks. From the documentation:

"A value of `'*'` will match anything; in this case you are responsible to provide your own validation of the Host header (perhaps in a middleware; if so this middleware must be listed first in MIDDLEWARE)."

More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

Answer (score 1):

I sympathise, having also spent too long on this. But just fixed it today, with as little as the following added into settings.py (and everything else 'out of the box' from Django re password reset).

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' # this is exactly the value 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = SENDGRID_API_KEY
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```